# Cloned Heroku app not working remotely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I wanted to create another cloned version of my existing heroku app on heroku.
For that i cloned it to my local machine then create a new heroku app and push the code to the newly created app.

I also pulled the db from the prev similar app and pushed it to my new app db.
But when i ran my rake db:migrate command i got this error

** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment

rake aborted!
can't convert Symbol into Integer

```
/app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:51:in `[]'
/app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:51:in `initialize'
/app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:812:in `new'
/app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:812:in `gem'
/app/config/environment.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:111:in `run'
/app/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/app/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
/app/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/app/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:605:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:594:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block in top_level'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in `top_level'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:in `run'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

Also when i run the application it crashes and the following error is shown in the heroku logs

```
2011-06-22T08:47:39+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET glowing-flower-236.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2011-06-22T08:47:40+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET glowing-flower-236.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2011-06-22T08:47:40+00:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 2.91.6.132 | 796 | http | 503
```

Do let me know where i am doing the things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the field type on your column name. Go through your schema and look at all of your tables. Make sure all have been dumped into `db/schema.rb`. Then look at each column type.

For example:

```
t.intgre
#should be 
t.integer
```

I have got the error you are getting for this exact reason many times over. It's a pain in the ass to fix. You will have to drop that table, fix the spelling, and then start over.

Comment: No this isn't the case. Ive checked that. The app which im trying to upload is the same working app which i cloned on my local system from heroku.